# Intersystems Cache Dummy Table

Tags: intersystems-cache

Does Intersystems Cache database have a dummy table similar to Oracle's `DUAL`?

I want to do something similar to:

```
SELECT 1; -- mysql
-- or
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL; -- oracle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older versions of Cache do not support this.  You can create a dummy table yourself called DUAL or DUMMY.  Newer versions of Cache (2009.1+) support select with no FROM clause.